# How can I switch between two cameras after a rotation of an object has finished?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationPlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject head;
    public GameObject[] cameras;

    private Animator anim;
    private bool started = true;
    private float animationLenth;
    private bool rotateHead = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(started == true)
        {
            anim.enabled = true;
            anim.Play("New State", 0, 0);
            animationLenth = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;
            StartCoroutine(AnimationEnded());
            started = false;
        }

        if (rotateHead == true)
        {
            cameras[0].SetActive(false);
            cameras[1].SetActive(true);
            anim.enabled = false;
            head.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(head.transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(head.transform.localRotation.x, head.transform.localRotation.y, 0f), 1.0f * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AnimationEnded()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animationLenth);
        anim.enabled = false;
        rotateHead = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is in this part :

```
if (rotateHead == true)
            {
                cameras[0].SetActive(false);
                cameras[1].SetActive(true);
                anim.enabled = false;
                head.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(head.transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(head.transform.localRotation.x, head.transform.localRotation.y, 0f), 1.0f * Time.deltaTime);
            }
```

I'm making the cameras switching before the rotation even start, what I need is somehow to make the camera switching when the rotation is end. Not after the rotation start but when the rotation is end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know what rotation you want to finish at, you can change cameras once you have reached that rotation.

Create and initialize a variable outside of the Update method:

```
private bool isFinishedTurning = false;
```

Then check whether the turn is completed in your update method and change cameras if it is complete:

```
if (rotateHead == true) {
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(head.transform.localRotation.x, head.transform.localRotation.y, 0f);
    head.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(head.transform.localRotation, targetRotation, 1.0f * Time.deltaTime);

    // Check whether the current localRotation is the same as the target rotation
    if (head.transform.localRotation == targetRotation) {
        isFinishedTurning = true;
    }
}

// If the rotation is complete, swap cameras and disable animation
if (isFinishedTurning == true) {
    cameras[0].SetActive(false);
    cameras[1].SetActive(true);
    anim.enabled = false;
    isFinishedTurning = false;
}
```